# Remote Access to Jupyter Notebook on AWS Windows Server

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I have seen many instances and tutorials for connecting remotely to Jupyter Notebook using a Linux based EC2 Instance on AWS.

for example: https://blog.keras.io/running-jupyter-notebooks-on-gpu-on-aws-a-starter-guide.html

I am wondering if the same is possible on a AWS windows server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the same is possible on a Windows server. Here are the links directly from AWS on how to set up on how to configure jupyter notebook and a Windows client on a EC2 instance

[Configure Jupyter Notebook](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mxnet/latest/dg/setup-jupyter-configure-server.html)

[Configure Windows client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mxnet/latest/dg/setup-jupyter-configure-client-windows.html)